# Loop analysis in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to do some analysis on several variables.
I have a dataset called "data". Thanks to someone's suggestion here I have managed to make histograms in a loop like this:

```
my_vars <- c("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4") # I have changed the names of the variables for "privacy"

par(mfcol=c(1,1))
for(v in my_vars) {
  hist(data[[v]], probability = TRUE, main=v, xlab="")
  lines(density(data[[v]]), col=2)
}
```

Now, I am trying to do the same thing with some analysis like this:

```
for(v in my_vars) {
  shapRes= shapiro.test(data[[v]])
  shapRes
}
```

However, when I run this latest part this is all I get in the console:

```
> for(v in my_vars) {
+   shapRes= shapiro.test(data[[v]])
+   shapRes
+ }
>
```

If I open "shapRes" this is what I see:

> Shapiro-Wilk normality test
>
> data:  data[[v]]
> W = 0.9561, p-value = 0.09105

I think that this is just the result of the last one. Does anybody know how can I fix this?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You are overwriting shapRes each iteration, you need to save it in a different location. Also, to print in a loop use print().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store each shapRes. I would recommend to use a list to store them:

```
mylist <- list()

for(v in my_vars) {
  shapRes= shapiro.test(data[[v]])
  mylist[[v]] <- shapRes
}
```

Comment: Why not use `lapply()`?

Comment: You are right, this works :O
I have to say, this would have been obvious to me if I was using Matlab (I am more proficient in that one). Can't believe I missed it here.

I have tried lapply but was also having problems with that. Can I ask you how would you do it with lapply?

Comment: For future reference, in case anyone ever needs it, I just wanted to print the results for each analysis on screen and with the variable name. So, in the end, this worked really well for me: 

my_vars <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")

for(v in my_vars) {
  skew = skewness(data[[v]])
  kurt = kurtosis(data[[v]])
  message(v)
  print(skew)
  print(kurt)
}